# UNIX Sed and inverse string search

Tags: bash, unix, sed

I have a simple (at least I thought it was) assignment where I have to use sed to replace a string with my username in a file. Lets say that it content looks like this:

```
1)
2)
3)
3) www
www 3)
3)
7)
```

The assignment has 3 parts:

-replace '3)' with your username. This command works just fine:

```
  sed -e "s/3)/$USER/" file
```

-replace '3)' with your id only in lines with 'www' string. With minor improvements the command form the first part also gets the job done:

```
  sed -e "/www/ s/3)/$USER/" file
```

In the last part of the assignment I have to replace 3) with my id only in the lines without 'www'. Is there a simple way to reverse search for a string using sed? so far I've come up with an idea to negate a set of 3 characters inside '[]' but sadly it doesn't really work.

```
  sed -e "/[^/(www/)]/ s/3)/$USER/" file
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `!` after the address. Note that most shells use ! as a history expansion character, so it must be properly quoted:

```
sed -e '/www/!s/3)/'"$USER/" file
```

Comment: After I fixed the quotes Your solutions works great         sed -e "/www/! s/3)/$USER/" file           Thanks!

Comment: I'm asking just out of pure curiosity: is there a way to make shell interpret only the $USER part as a variable if the rest is in single quotes? If i try to use '/www/!s/3)/ "$USER/"' shell interprets $USER as a normal string

Comment: On the command line, ! in double quotes is still special. Quotes aren't nested in bash, but you only need to quote the ) and the username, so `/www/!s/3')'/"$USER"/` should work.

Comment: So every time I use the s/// only the characters that shell might interpret as special need to be in single quotes, and if there are none I can skip them altogether?

Comment: That's not related to s///, that's how shell quoting works. Some characters are special for the shell, they need to be quoted.

Comment: Thanks for explaining this to me. I've always thought that the whole expression in-between  -e and the file name needs to be in single/ double quotes.

Comment: No, sed doesn't need any quotes. They're there to prevent the shell from interpreting some of the characters before it passes the string to sed.